# Data storage class with single setter enforcement

Tags: c++, database

We have a simple data storage class implemented as a singleton with a `get()` and `set()` function that takes a key to look up the data and has the ability to serialize/unserialize its data for persistence.  We're trying to add the ability to enforce having only one setter/owner (object?) for the data.

One idea we had was passing `this` casted to a void pointer.

`bool_t data::set(void* owner, key_t key, int32_t value)`

Maybe we could do this in the owner's constructor, but it doesn't add much as we'd still have to call `set()` with a pointer to verify:

`bool_t data::claim(void* owner, key_t key)`

The set function would save the void pointer, and verify the subsequent sets all have matching pointers.

I don't really like this since we'll have a bunch of `this` in our codebase.  Is there any strategy or pattern that's better than this?  I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Why would you write `(void*)&this` instead of `this`?

Comment: `(void*)&this` won't compile. Just pass `this`, it's convertible to `void*`

Comment: Whoops.  You're right.  That's less ugly.  Updated.